# Replace array value with array key using the '&' issue in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["order_reference"]=>
    string(9) "200123130"
    ["store_reference"]=>
....
  [1]
array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["order_reference"]=>
    string(9) "20222220"
    ["store_reference"]=>
...
```

I would like to have this array:

```
array(4) {
  [200123130]=>
  array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["order_reference"]=>
    string(9) "200123130"
    ["store_reference"]=>
....
  [20222220]
array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(6)
    ["order_reference"]=>
    string(9) "20222220"
    ["store_reference"]=>
...
```

This is what I tried:

```
$i = 0;
    foreach ($data['data'] as &$key) {
        $data['data'][$key['order_reference']] = array_values($data['data'][$i]);
        $i++;
    }
```

But I  get the a bigger array, starting like:

```
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  &array(34) {
    ["id"]=>
```

Any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: `$key` is the reference so your problem is you are still addressing `$data` in your loop

Comment: What you do wrong is, that you simply add a new element to the array with the new key. You do not delete the old one. At the end of oyur loop you should have double as much entreis in your array. The arrays with the correct keys should have lost their inner array keys though, because you call `array_values()` on the inner ekys, which makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
$newarray = array_combine(array_column($orig, "order_reference"), $orig);
```

- array_combine() -- Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values
- array_column() -- Return the values from a single column in the input array

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a single call to `array_column` using the third `$index_key` parameter:

```
$new = array_column($orig, null, 'order_reference');
```

See https://eval.in/972672